# Google AdMob Publisher data not found. error iOS

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have a problem with AdMob.I add all implementations for AdMob.When I tried I had an error: Publisher data not found. Then I searched on google. They mention to check id but it is no problem with my id. (My ad type is rewarded)

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Google gives next recommendations:

> ...Always test with test ads
>
> When building and testing your apps, make sure you use test ads rather
> than live, production ads. Failure to do so can lead to suspension of
> your account.
>
> The easiest way to load test ads is to use our dedicated test ad unit
> ID for iOS rewarded ads:
>
> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313
>
> It's been specially configured to return test ads for every request,
> and you're free to use it in your own apps while coding, testing, and
> debugging. Just make sure you replace it with your own ad unit ID
> before publishing your app...

More information [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded?hl=uk#objective-c_2)

Comment: test ad  work fine but when use real ad it show this error all dat assign correctly

Comment: but when we will publish app, we have to show other ads instead of test ads.... what we have to do there?